# How to make Vue component work with v-model preserving value type?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

### Problem

When I'm having a `v-model` on a HTML `<select>`, `v-model` is setting the given property to selected value preserving types of that values - if I bind a number to `<option>`, model property is set to number, if I bind an Object it's set to that Object.

```
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    options: [5, 10, 15, 'text', { 'description': 'I am an Object' }],
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <select v-model="model">
    <option
      v-for="option in options"
      :value="option"
    >
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
<template>
```

I'm having a `<base-select>` custom component, which is wrapping the usage of `<select>` tag for me. I'm trying to implement the same `v-model` behavior for it, but am failing, because the types are not preserved - I'm returned Strings all the time, even when I'm binding numbers or objects.

```
//// BaseSelect.vue

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    value: {
      required: true
    }
  },
};
</script>
<template>
  <select
    :value="value"
    @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
  >
    <option
      v-for="option in options"
      :value="option"
    >
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

//// App.vue

<script>
  @import 'BaseSelect' from './BaseSelect';

  export default {
    components: {
      BaseSelect,
    },
    data: {
      options: [5, 10, 15, 'text', { 'description': 'I am an Object' }],
    }
  };
</script>
<template>
  <base-select
    v-model="model"
    :options="options"
  />
<template>
```

### Fiddle

Here is where this behaviour is clearly visible: http://jsfiddle.net/4o67pzLs/14/

The first select is preserving types of values bound to model, while the other one is all the time setting values to Strings.

### Question

Is it possible to implement `v-model` on custom component, which would preserve types? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how we finally did it along with @RobertKusznier :

- Bind the select with a computed property of the component using `v-model`
- Define a getter and setter for that computed property
- The getter returns the value of the component
- The setter emits the change event

It preserves the type of the selected option's value and doesn't mutate the component's value.

Credit goes to @RobertKusznier who suggested we didn't mutate the value of the component.

```js
let baseSelect = {
 props: {
   options: {
     type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    value: {
     required: true
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
   valueCopy: {
     get() {
       return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
       this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    }
  },
  
  template: `
   <select
      v-model="valueCopy"
    >
      <option
        v-for="option in options"
        :value="option"
      >
        {{ option }}
      </option>
    </select>
  `,
};

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  components: {
   baseSelect
  },
  data: {
   model: 5,
    options: [5, 10, 15, 'text', new Date()]
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <select v-model="model">
        <option
          v-for="option in options"
          :value="option">
            {{ option }}
        </option>
      </select>
      
      <base-select
        v-model="model"
        :options="options"
        :sister="10"
      />
      
      <p>model: {{ model }}</p>
      <p>typeof model: {{ typeof model }}</p>
    </div>
  `
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work in my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gswbfLde/5/) (I see it works in your example). Do you know why?

Comment: In your component, you added the `model` object in the `props` object. Move it at the root of your baseSelect object and it should work : http://jsfiddle.net/23tLge6u/

Comment: True :). Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Okay, I simplified the code to omit `model` in component settings: http://jsfiddle.net/gswbfLde/20/. The only thing that worries me in your solution is mutating component prop. In the past I've seen warnings in console to not do that. But in this code I don't see them. I'm still investigating that...

Comment: Yeah, I tried the same solution in my app (not in JSFiddle) and got that warning: `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"`. I'd like to avoid such warnings. Also I agree with the warning and think that mutating a prop is not a clean solution.

Comment: I think I managed to do it without mutating the prop: http://jsfiddle.net/gswbfLde/28/. **EDIT**: No, it won't work when parent mutates the property `value`.

Comment: I understand what's the problem, but I still don't know how to implement it cleanly (without mutating `value` prop). Do you know how? Here you have a fiddle to experiment with: http://jsfiddle.net/gswbfLde/38/. The problem occurs, when you change the value in the first select - it doesn't update in the second one.

Comment: Okay, I've done it using computed property with getter and setter: http://jsfiddle.net/gswbfLde/43/. This solution seems to work and be clean.

Comment: It doesn't mutate it in the setter. The only thing setter does is emit an event - then the value gets mutated in the parent, and only then the value gets uptated in the child. Where do you think I mutate the `value` prop?

Comment: @RobertKusznier No, you're right. It's changed after it's been updated in the parent. My bad.

Comment: If you update your answer to any solution which doesn't mutate props and generate warnings, I'll accept it.

Comment: I edited the snippet and explanations.  Thanks for your question. I'm still kinda new to Vuejs and it was an interesting example.

Comment: And I thank you for figuring out the solution with me :). I'm also pretty new to Vue.